# Move subgroup under repeated main group while keeping main group once in data.frame R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm aware that the question is awkward. If I could phrase it better I'd probably find the solution in an other thread.

I have this data structure...

```r
df <- data.frame(group = c("X", "F", "F", "F", "F", "C", "C"),
                 subgroup = c(NA, "camel", "horse", "dog", "cat", "orange", "banana"))
```

... and would like to turn it into this...

```r
data.frame(group = c("X", "F", "camel", "horse", "dog", "cat", "C", "orange", "banana"))
```

... which is surprisingly confusing. Also, I would prefer not using a loop.

EDIT: I updated the example to clarify that solutions that depend on sorting  unfortunately do not do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an (edited) answer with new data.
Using `data.table` is going to help a lot. The idea is to split the df into groups and `lapply()` to each group what we need. Whe have to take care of some things meanwhile.

```
library(data.table)
# set as data.table
setDT(df)

# to mantain the ordering, you need to put as factor the group.
# the levels are going to give the ordering infos to split
df[,':='(group = factor(group, levels =unique(df$group)))]

# here the split function, splitting df int a list
df_list <-split(df, df$group, sorted =F)

# now you lapply to each element what you need
df_list <-lapply(df_list, function(x) data.frame(group = unique(c(as.character(x$group),x$subgroup))))

# put into a data.table and remove NAs
rbindlist(df_list)[!is.na(df_onecol$group)]

    group
1:      X
2:      F
3:  camel
4:  horse
5:    dog
6:    cat
7:      C
8: orange
9: banana
```

Comment: Compelling and technically correct but it depends on sorting. Maybe I should have written a more generic example.

Comment: @Patrick gotcha probably, see edit.

Comment: @Patrick last edit should work.

Answer (score 1):

With the edited data we need to add another column (here row_number) to sort by:

```
df %>%
 pivot_longer(col = everything()) %>%
 mutate(r_n = row_number()) %>% 
 group_by(value) %>% slice(1) %>%
 arrange(r_n) %>%
 filter(!is.na(value))

#output 

# A tibble: 9 × 3
# Groups:   value [9]
  name     value    r_n
  <chr>    <chr>  <int>
1 group    X          1
2 group    F          3
3 subgroup camel      4
4 subgroup horse      6
5 subgroup dog        8
6 subgroup cat       10
7 group    C         11
8 subgroup orange    12
9 subgroup banana    14
```

Comment: Very nice! Maybe put `slice(1) %>%` in its own row for readability.